# Unable to start my Android application using Android App Linking

Tags: android, deep-linking, applinks, android-deep-link, android-app-links

I want my application to start when my user types a specific URL in his browser. To do so, I implemented Android App Linking using this documentation : https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks .

I created my assetlinks.json file using the Google Digital Asset Links tool (https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator), and it says me it's working properly :

[image]

So I uploaded the generated file in the '.well-known/assetlinks.json' location :

[image]

I set an intent filter in my manifest linked to the specified URL, like this :

[image]

And then I tried the ADB command to check if my link is verified and it is :

[image]

So I don't understand why when I type my URL the app does not start. Am I missing something?

Comment: If I remember correctly Android App Linking becomes active if you click on a link in your web browser like Chrome. If you enter the address in the address bar you will get the web page instead. You can test that with links to apps in Google Play Store.